# code ignored after first button click

Tags: c#, button

This button (`loginButton`) does everything it's supposed to on the first click. Then, on all subsequent clicks, it refuses change the text of `loginStatusLabel` at the beginning and end of the method...why? It's as if the code is completely skipped over for with no explanation. The debug messages before and afterword both come through fine, and `loginStatusLabel` isn't referenced anywhere else.

Am I an idiot?

```
    private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Write("Changing label...");
        loginStatusLabel.Text = "STATUS: Running..."; //this line is ignored after the first iteration
        Debug.WriteLine("label changed.");
        loginButton.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            string LDS01_start = "select count(*) from BBLEARN.AUTH_PROVIDER_LOG where AUTH_PROVIDER_PK1 = 103 ";
            string LDAPS_start = "select count(*) from BBLEARN.AUTH_PROVIDER_LOG where AUTH_PROVIDER_PK1 = 106 ";
            string middle = "and log_date >= '" + GetDate(loginStartDate) + @"' 
                         and log_date < '" + GetDate(loginEndDate) + @"' ";

            string LDS01_0 = LDS01_start + middle + "and event_type = 0";
            string LDS01_1 = LDS01_start + middle + "and event_type = 1";
            string LDS01_2 = LDS01_start + middle + "and event_type = 2";
            string LDS01_5 = LDS01_start + middle + "and event_type = 5";
            string LDS01_6 = LDS01_start + middle + "and event_type = 6";

            string LDAPS_0 = LDAPS_start + middle + "and event_type = 0";
            string LDAPS_1 = LDAPS_start + middle + "and event_type = 1";
            string LDAPS_2 = LDAPS_start + middle + "and event_type = 2";
            string LDAPS_5 = LDAPS_start + middle + "and event_type = 5";
            string LDAPS_6 = LDAPS_start + middle + "and event_type = 6";

            GetData(LDS01_0, LDS01_LB0);
            GetData(LDS01_1, LDS01_LB1);
            GetData(LDS01_2, LDS01_LB2);
            GetData(LDS01_5, LDS01_LB5);
            GetData(LDS01_6, LDS01_LB6);

            GetData(LDAPS_0, LDAPS_LB0);
            GetData(LDAPS_1, LDAPS_LB1);
            GetData(LDAPS_2, LDAPS_LB2);
            GetData(LDAPS_5, LDAPS_LB5);
            GetData(LDAPS_6, LDAPS_LB6);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception);
        }
        loginButton.Enabled = true;

        Debug.Write("Changing label...");
        loginStatusLabel.Text = "STATUS: Complete";
        Debug.WriteLine("label changed.");
    }

    private void GetData(string selectCommand, Label label)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Getting data for " + label.Name + "...");
        //open the connection
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectString);
        conn.Open();
        Debug.WriteLine("Connection open...");           

        //define the command
        selectCommand = selectCommand.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
        OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand, conn);
        OracleCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OracleCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        //run the command
        Debug.WriteLine("Running command...");
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        Debug.WriteLine("Command complete.");
        //close the connection
        conn.Close();

        Invoke(new Action(() => RenderData(label, table.Rows[0][0].ToString())));
    }

    private void RenderData(Label label, string text)
    {
        label.Text = text;
    }
```

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread for the entire duration of all of the work that you're doing.  You need to not do that.

Comment: How so? I'm confused, the ``invoke`` command closes the new thread automatically...right?

Comment: No, it runs the provided code on the UI thread, but you're already on the UI thread to begin with, so it effectively does nothing.  You never create any other threads (and that's your problem).

Comment: Grr, I knew I'd missed something stupid. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to create the new thread in the first place. I'm stupid.